# Can not highlight overfull line's column with vim

Tags: vim

I am quite new in customizing my .vimrc so it is almost "vanilla".
I want to higlight 81th line's column when line is overfull.
So I inserted this in my .vimrc :

```
:highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=red  
:call matchadd('ColorColumn', '\%81v', 100)
```

The problem is that it seems to stop working after a certain amount of opened windows or buffers.

Comment: it has nothing to do with the number of windows/buffers you opened. some ft plugin may change the local setting. very likely, when you open a certain file, this setting was overwritten. You should find it out.  btw, you can just `set colorcolumn=80` instead of matcheadd()

Comment: Ok i will try to find it out.
The matched() thing only highlight the column when the line is overfull, if i set colorcolumn as you say, i will have the whole column highlighted.

Comment: matchadd is window local i believe, so you have to add it to every window (or maybe buffer)